# count grandchildren of an object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi I'm currently building a little forum application with rails (3). I'm fairly new in the Rails matter and I got stuck when I want to pull the top boards (a board belongs to a forum) specified with a forum id).

"defining a top board": a board belonging to a specific forum_id who has the most topic_replies & topic.

"the family tree": Forum > Board > Topic > TopicReply

my models:

```
**forum.rb**

class Forum < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'display_order ASC'
  has_many :boards, :dependent => :destroy
end


**board.rb**

class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :order => 'display_order ASC'

  belongs_to :forum
  has_many :topics, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :topic_replies, :through => :topics

  def latest_topic_reply
    t = TopicReply.find_by_sql("SELECT tr.* from topic_replies tr, topics t where tr.topic_id = t.id AND t.board_id = #{self.id} ORDER BY tr.updated_at desc LIMIT 1;")[0]
  end
end


**topic.rb**

class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :board
  has_many :topic_replies, :dependent => :destroy
end


**topic_reply.rb**

class TopicReply < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :topic
end
```

In SQL I would do this:

```
"SELECT b.* FROM boards b,topics t WHERE t.board_id=b.id AND b.forum_id=2 GROUP BY board_id ORDER BY SUM(t.topic_replies_count) DESC LIMIT 4;"
```

I prefer to manage this with active records though (or is this not better then the SQL?), I'm not too familiar with it just yet. Could anyone push me in the right direction please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make it work like this:

```
Board.joins(:topics).where(:forum_id => @forum.id).order(:topic_replies_count).to_sql
```

By using `to_sql` you can see what SQL it generates. The `topic_replies_count` would be a [counter cache column](http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column) in `Topic` that holds the current number of associated topic replies.

See the details about Rails 3 querying in the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Comment: thanks for the reference for the cache column, didn't know that yet. Still haven't found the right ActiveRecord yet, but I added the right SQL.

Comment: What do you mean by "haven't found the right AR"? If you replace the `.to_sql` with `.all` for example, this piece of code will return the collection or `Boards` that you need, ordered correctly.